# Problem to input custom HTML with schema and JavaScript to individual page modx

Tags: modx-revolution, modx-templates

I'm new on ModX. I've created a template variable to input custom HTML into my page. I choose **Rich Text** as input type for this template variable.

On the other hand, my HTML contains some meta tag like `<meta itemprop="name" content="myname">` tag with schema ( some custom attributes like `<div class="review" itemprop="review" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">` )

So when I submit this data into page through template variable, I don't see that meta tag and custom attributes like **itemprop**, **itemscope** or **script** tag. They are removed or ignored by the editor.

Can someone tell me that how can I get rid from these issue? I will be great full for the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways at least:

1) use textarea TV type instead rich text
2) it depends on your WYSIWYG editor, they allow you to exclude (not cut) the specified tags from processing